# Is it possible to toggle child viewport visibility from the parent in the outliner?

Tags: interface, 3d-view, outliner

Is it possible to toggle child viewport visibility from the parent object in the outliner? (Can viewport visibility be applied hierarchically?)

Comment: Would anybody know how to animate the visibility of these child objects? I have more than 300 child objects in one empty and would like to hide and show them on certain keyframes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> *(makes the command recursive)* when toggling the visibility of the parent and it will also apply to all the children in the hierarchy. The same goes for all the other toggle operations.

Additionally, you can drag over multiple icons and toggle these.

Comment: I was fighting with the outliner, not knowing about this. Thank you !! As much as I love Blender, the UI is a freakin' nightmare.

Comment: It seems to have changed to `Shift` + `LMB` in newer Blender versions.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> click (LMB ~ left mouse button) the visibility "eye" to recursively hide & show child objects from a parent.

Pro-Tip: You'll also see this hot-key suggestion if you hover over the visibility eye icon:

[image: screencast - toggle child visibility]